# How to reset Mate-Terminal default-profile-settings?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, linux-mint

While setting up an old laptop with Mint for a friend, I(being a bit cheeky and smart) ticked the "Run a custom command instead of my shell", The custom command being; echo and some rather rude text. I thought this would print the rather rude text when he opened the terminal. Now when I launch the terminal the window flashes open for a second and then is gon, and it does this from every instance of the launcher. I have tried finding the profile settings for hours by greping every possible combination of strings imaginable and am now considering a reinstall, can I reset this checkbox from the command line and if so... HOW ??
relative newbi obviously.

Answer (score 3):

In recent MATE versions the program settings are kept in dconf. Thus:

```
dconf reset -f /org/mate/terminal/
```

Older versions used a GConf fork called "mateconf":

```
mateconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/mate-terminal
```